# Is Visual Composer compatible with divi?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying out some wordpress builders and themes lately, I would just like to ask some wordpress guru's here if its okay for me to install visual composer plugin to my divi theme? As you know visual composer is a builder tool while the divi theme has its own builder too. The reason I want to install visual composer is that there are some features there that I really like which I cant find in divi. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by theory yes it is compatible with Divi.. but in reality , Divi And VC are bloated as it is.. highly Not recommended using them both together..